# ionic ios app + TTS plugin is not working

Tags: ios, angularjs, plugins, ionic-framework, text-to-speech

In my ionic project , i am using TTS plugin.

```
    $scope.speakText = function(data) {
  TTS.speak({
         text: data,
         locale: 'en-US',
         rate: 1.0
     }, function () {
         // Do Something after success
          console.log('Speech complete');
     }, function (reason) {
         // Handle the error case
          console.log('Speech error');
     });
};
```

Getting the below error while running in web browser.

> ReferenceError: TTS is not defined
>       at Scope.$scope.speakText (appcontroller.js:332)
>       at appcontroller.js:32
>       at ionic.bundle.js:32328
>       at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:19199)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:19475

Getting the below error while running the same in ipad device. " Error: Can't find variable: TTS "
    The same code is working in another project.I am newbie. I donot know where the problem is? Please give some solutions.